# How to put data from my database into select in angular

Tags: angular

I want to allow the user to be able to choose their email that has been entered beforehand but when I used ng-options and I have tried ngFor but it still doesn't seem to work, did I do it wrong or something?

transfer.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="transFunds()" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
          <select [ngModel]="selectedName" (ngModelChange)="updateSelectedValue($event)">
              <option *ngFor ="let recipient of recipients" value="{{recipient.emailTo}}">{{recipient.emailTo}}</option>
        </select>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
          <p><input type="number"  placeholder="Amount Transfering" [(ngModel)]="amount"></p>
        </div>  
      </div>  
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <p><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button> </p>    
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

transfer.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { PostsService } from '../posts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transfer',
  templateUrl: './transfer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transfer.component.css']
})
export class TransferComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: Http, private router: Router, private auth: AuthService,private postsService: PostsService) { }
  transfer = {};
  recipients: any;
  transferForm: FormGroup;
  public userEmail: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.transferForm = this.fb.group({
      emailTo: '',
      amount: ''
    });
    this.auth.currentEmail.subscribe(email => this.userEmail = email);

    this.postsService.getAllRecipient().subscribe(recipient => {
      this.recipients = recipient;
    });
  }      

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do like this in my code , make use of `*ngfor` available in angular js 2

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedName"="selectedName"   
    (ngModelChange)="updateSelectedValue($event)">
        <option *ngFor ="let recipient of recipients" 
           value="{{recipient.email}}">{{recipient.email}}</option>
</select>
```

I think `value="{{recipient.email}}"` is need to be replace by Id of receipient so it will be like `value="{{recipient.Id}}"`

Comment: sorry I mean `([ngModel])="selectedName"`

Comment: @KUROYUKI - ok, i thouhg you want one way binding only ...changed answer as you required two way binding ...i suggest to make use of ngModleChange when you want to do extra logic on change...

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up angularjs and angular syntax, it should be,

```
 <select class="form-control" name="someDrpDown" [(ngModel)]="selectedName">
        <option *ngFor="let recpient of recipients" [ngValue]="recipient">
          {{recpient.email}}
        </option> 
  </select>
```

Comment: not sure but havent seem soemting like  recipients()

Comment: ok because i am learning angular and i though its kind of new sytax

Comment: haha that sounds funny! between is there a difference in yours and mine?

Comment: I have tried this method but it doesn't work for me too I have tried it before. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

or you can create a custom directive like *ngFor.

that is to implement my own ngFor directive that would be capable of iterating through ES6 iterables.

Comment: I have tried this method but it doesn't work for me too I have tried it before. thanks anyway.